# how to convert laravel Elequent to collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get specific columns of records in laravel and export them to excel but I get this error.
I'm using cyber-duck/laravel-excel package

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Cyberduck\LaravelExcel\Exporter\AbstractSpreadsheet::load() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection, instance of stdClass given,
>   called in
>   /home/vagrant/code/sdf/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ApplicantsController.php
>   on line 51

This is my Code:

```
    public function export()
    {
        $applicants = Applicant::select('first_name','second_name','third_name','last_name',
            'qualification','birth_date','card_no','card_source','mobile','home','computer','english',
            'work','sex','course_id')->get();
        $fileName = 'applicants.xlsx';
        $excel = Exporter::make('Excel');
        $excel->load($applicants);
        return $excel->stream($fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `->loadQuery` instead and remove the `->get()` from the `$applicants`?

Comment: I get this error :Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::loadQuery()

Comment: Btw, I'm using laravel 5.4

Comment: Give it a try. `$excel->load(collect($applicants->toArray()));`

Comment: @user2094178 select/get() itself should return a collection, I don't know any situation when it returns stdClass?

Comment: @Vladan it does return a collection, but it's an eloquent collection (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection). Why it would be saying it's an instance of stdClass I am not sure, it may just be a generic exception this package throws if it doesn't get the right type of collection. using the collect($applicants->toArray()) will turn it into an support collection

Comment: `get()` will give you `Illuminate\Eloquent\Collection` and not a model instance, if empty, you will get an empty object, check what you are getting for `get()`, empty or collection of records.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks for help .^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:

```
public function export()
    {
        $applicants = DB::table('applicants')->select('first_name','second_name','third_name','last_name',
            'qualification','birth_date','card_no','card_source','mobile','home','computer','english',
            'work','sex','course_id')->get()->toArray();
            $app = collect($applicants);
        $fileName = 'applicants.xlsx';
        return $collection = Exporter::make('Excel')->load($app)->setSerialiser(new ApplicantSerializer)->stream($fileName);
    }
```